# How Upper Bound and Lower Bound internal implementation works?

Tags: c++

So I was lately using upper bound and lower bound functions and I was curious about the internal implementation of these functions so I dig into it. But, now I am quite confused to identify the distinctive behavior in between them based on their internal implementation. Both of them used binary search algorithm; that's for sure but there is nothing difference in their internal implementation, WHY!!! I believe that these two functions aren't same because, for example....

```
5 //number of elements inside an array
3 3 3 3 4 //elements
lower bound of 3 will give index 0 
upper bound of 3 will give index 3
```

Upper Bound Internal Implementation:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T, class Compare>
ForwardIt upper_bound(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value, Compare comp)
{
    ForwardIt it;
    typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::difference_type count, step;
    count = std::distance(first, last);
 
    while (count > 0) {
        it = first; 
        step = count / 2;
        std::advance(it, step);
        if (!comp(value, *it)) {
            first = ++it;
            count -= step + 1;
        } 
        else
            count = step;
    }
    return first;
}
```

Lower Bound Internal Implementation:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T, class Compare>
ForwardIt lower_bound(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value, Compare comp)
{
    ForwardIt it;
    typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::difference_type count, step;
    count = std::distance(first, last);
 
    while (count > 0) {
        it = first;
        step = count / 2;
        std::advance(it, step);
        if (comp(*it, value)) {
            first = ++it;
            count -= step + 1;
        }
        else
            count = step;
    }
    return first;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a diffing tool be more appropriate?

Comment: You can see the difference in the if statement. See `!comp()` vs. `comp()`.

Comment: Don't you see a difference between `if (!comp(value, *it))` and `if (comp(*it, value))`?

Comment: Yeah about that!!! Reasons they are same: 1. comp(*it,value) means, return *it<value
2. comp(value,*it) means, return value<*it so both are points to same meaning.

Comment: No they're not... and did you see the `!`?

Comment: yeah, that's why they are same. Didn't you guys see that there is a change in parameters position in the comp() function?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the conditions.

`!comp(value, *it)` - "`value` is not ordered before `*it`"

`comp(*it, value)` - "`*it` is ordered before `value`"

These do not mean the same thing.
For instance, `!(a < b)` (that is, `a >= b`) is not equivalent to `b < a`.

Comment: Oh. Got your point. I thought that !(a<b) is equivalent to b<a. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: @codosopher: C++ is getting a new `<=>` operator. That's because there are 3 possibilities, `a<b`, `b<a`, or `(!a<b) && (!b<a)`.

Comment: @MSalters WOW! I don't know that. Three-way comparison operator, that's prolific. Thank you for that. But I don't see that how's it useful in our daily real life problems.